# Rendering the current page with form errors

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-forms

See the code below.

```
<!-- in index.html -->
<form role="form" action="/messages/create/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
        ...
</form>

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           ...
        else:
          return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'form': form}) 
          #this redirects to /messages/create/, but I want to look at /index, with the form errors.
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please post your complete code, and the exact errors you are receiving, what is in the `...` of your template?

Comment: No errors. When the form is invalid, the user is redirected to `/messages/create/` because it's specified in `form action`, but I'd like to redirect him to `/index`. I can just `redirect('/')` but then I would lose the `form.errors` and the user cannot see why the form is invalid (e.g. password not present, etc.)

Comment: @MaximusS, your code as stated will not do a redirect, unless your frontend HTML/JS is doing a redirect.

Comment: It's rendering the `index.html` template at the url `/messages/create/` when the form is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the form is getting posted to `"/messages/create/"`, a page with this url will be rendered. And you yourself mentioned, if we do a redirect, we'll lose the form data. I'm assuming that the url of the page from where the form is getting posted is `/index`.

You can do the following:

1. While showing the form errors, let the url remain at `/messages/create/`, but just render the html of `/index` page with the form data and errors.
2. Always display the url `/index` , but post the form data to `/messages/create/` using ajax, then display errors or any other messages using javascript.
3. From `/index` page, post the form to `/index` with an additional hidden parameter `action = "message_create"`. The based upon the value of `action`, call suitable method from the index method. This way you will remain at `/index` all the time.